# Factorial as a product of three consecutive natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, gamma-function

How to find the exact number of possible ways to represent a factorial as a product of three consecutive natural numbers?

$$m \cdot (m+1) \cdot (m+2) = n!$$

where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$

I found these cases:

$1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 3!\\2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 4!\\4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 = 5!\\8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 = 6!$

But I need to find the exact number of all possible cases using some formula (or maybe prove that there are only four cases).

Comment: You might consider primes less than $m$ and whether they can all be factors of $m$ or $m+1$ or $m+2$

Comment: Maybe, someone can prove that there is no further solution. What you should do first is to determine the (unique) positive solution of $x(x+1)(x+2)=n!$ for $n=1$ to , say , $n=100$ and check whether it is an integer. This will give already a huge lower bound for $m$ for a solution you still did not find. Another approach is to consider the largest prime factor of $m(m+1)(m+2)$. ALL smaller prime numbers must then divide $m(m+1)(m+2)$ which will very rarely be the case.

Comment: PARI/GP allows to check whether a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$. This reveals that there is no further solution for $n\le 8\ 000$ which is convincing enough for me , although it of course does not prove yet that there is no further solution.

Comment: @Peter, do you think it is possible to draw an analogy with [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem)?

Comment: @EuropeX This problem at least shows how difficult such equations are ususally to solve. If the problems are equivalent, we would be screwed, but I do not think this is the case.

Comment: According to [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h501433p2817711) it seems to be an open problem (I don't have the original source though). This question was already asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612872/573047) and there it is connected with the abc conjecture.

Comment: @BillyJoe, my question, although similar to the one you indicated, is different, because I'm not asking you to solve the equation, but at least calculate the number of cases that satisfy the equation.